# Struggling to find the Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, syntax-error

I have two tables and while I can create the first, the second won't because of the following error:

FOREIGN KEY(JClientID) REFERENCES CLIENT(ClientID) [ near ")": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Is this just a simple mistake?

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT
    (FName    VARCHAR(25)   NOT NULL,
     LName    VARCHAR(25)   NOT NULL,
     PhoneNum INTEGER(10)   NOT NULL,
     ClientID CHAR(5)       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ClientID));

CREATE TABLE JOB
    (DateDue    DATE()   NOT NULL,
     JobID    CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
     JClientID CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (JobID)
    FOREIGN KEY(JClientID) REFERENCES CLIENT(ClientID));
```

Comment: Hint:  Missing comma before `foreign key`.

Comment: Remove "()" from DateDue like this: `DateDue    DATE   NOT NULL,`

Comment: Thanks! That worked guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you forgot the comma after your primary key:

Change:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB
    (DateDue    DATE()   NOT NULL,
     JobID    CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
     JClientID CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (JobID)
    FOREIGN KEY(JClientID) REFERENCES CLIENT(ClientID));
```

to be:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB
    (DateDue    DATE   NOT NULL,
     JobID    CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
     JClientID CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (JobID),
    FOREIGN KEY(JClientID) REFERENCES CLIENT(ClientID));
```

Comment: Even with the comma, the error is the same. Appreciate it though

Comment: `DATE` has no parentheses

Comment: editied to remove parens

Comment: That worked, thanks so much